# Boto3 - Create S3 'object created' notification to trigger a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, boto3

How do I use boto3 to simulate the `Add Event Source` action on the AWS GUI Console in the `Event Sources` tab.

I want to programatically create a trigger such that if an object is created in  `MyBucket`, it will call `MyLambda` function(qualified with an alias).

The relevant api call that I see in the Boto3 documentation is `create_event_source_mapping` but it states explicitly that it is only for AWS Pull Model while I think that S3 belongs to the Push Model. Anyways, I tried using it but it didn't work.

Scenarios:

- Passing a prefix filter would be nice too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong side. This is configured on S3

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket_name = 'mybucket'
    bucket_notification = s3.BucketNotification(bucket_name)
    response = bucket_notification.put(
        NotificationConfiguration={'LambdaFunctionConfigurations': [
            {
                'LambdaFunctionArn': 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:033333333:function:mylambda:staging',
                'Events': [
                    's3:ObjectCreated:*'
                ],

            },
        ]})
```