# How to add s3 trigger function in the lambda function to read the file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to add a s3 trigger in the lambda function in the source code itself instead of creating a trigger in the aws console. I need that trigger to read a file when it is uploaded on a particular folder of S3 bucket. I have done this using the creating the s3 trigger in the console itself with help of prefix. Can someone help with of creating this s3 trigger in the lambda function source code itself. Below is the source code of the lambda function for reading the file.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        print("CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])
        return response['ContentType']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the code? Any errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boto3 - Create S3 'object created' notification to trigger a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925010/boto3-create-s3-object-created-notification-to-trigger-a-lambda-function)

Comment: This sounds like a weird setup - how will the lambda be triggered in the first place? And why do you want to readd the s3 notification each time the lambda is triggered? If you only want to know how to add s3-notifications using `boto3` this question is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925010/boto3-create-s3-object-created-notification-to-trigger-a-lambda-function

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Lambda function would presumably only be run when the trigger detects a new object.

However, you are asking how to create the trigger from the AWS Lambda function, but that function will only be run when a trigger exists.

So, it is a [Cart before the horse - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cart_before_the_horse) situation.

Instead, you can create the trigger in Amazon S3 from the AWS Lambda console or via an API call, but this is done as part of the definition of the Lambda function -- it can't be done from within the **source code** of the function, since it isn't run until the trigger already exists!